# Django signals > right approach?

Tags: django

In my **signals.py** I am doing the import for the function `unique_order_reference_generator` within the function `reserveditem_create_order_reference`. I wonder if that is the right approach, or is there a better solution?

file **utils.py**

```
from lumis.utils import get_random_string

from .models import Order, ReservedItem


def unique_order_reference_generator():

    new_id = get_random_string(length=10)

    reserved_item = ReservedItem.objects.filter(
        order_reference=new_id
    ).exists()
    order = Order.objects.filter(order_reference=new_id).exists()

    if reserved_item or order:
        return unique_order_reference_generator()  # TODO Marc: Test
    else:
        return new_id
```

file **signals.py**

```
# Generate order reference
def reserveditem_create_order_reference(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    from .utils import unique_order_reference_generator

    if not instance.order_reference:
        instance.order_reference = unique_order_reference_generator()
```

file **app.py**

```
class OrdersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'orders'

    def ready(self):

        #Pre save signal for ReservedItem model
        reserved_model = self.get_model('ReservedItem')
        pre_save.connect(
            reserveditem_create_order_reference,
            sender=reserved_model,
            dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier"
        )
```

Comment: any specific reason for doing this ?

Comment: Is it working for you? Are there any problems, performance issues or something else?

Comment: The other option would be to override the `ReservedItem.save()` method to assign the random `order_reference` there.

Comment: Hint: you could also change the `unique_order_reference_generator` function to use a while loop instead of recursion if you want to cut down on unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Hi Ralf, I think the .save method is a very good idea. Further, I am struggling to understand how to use the while loop will help to cut down the function. In the while loop, I would still have to check the order_reference already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments to the question I mentioned, as a side note, that you could refactor the function to avoid recursion.

This is not too important to the question on hand, but it could improve performance a little bit:

**utils.py**

```
from lumis.utils import get_random_string
from .models import Order, ReservedItem

def unique_order_reference_generator():
    # initial values
    reserved_item_exists = True
    order_exists = True

    while reserved_item_exists or order_exists:
        new_id = get_random_string(length=10)

        reserved_item_exists = ReservedItem.objects.filter(
            order_reference=new_id).exists()

        if not reserved_item_exists:
            # check 'Order' model only if there is no 'ReservedItem', because
            # why do a search in 'Order' when we already know that this
            # 'new_id' is taken
            order_exists = Order.objects.filter(
                order_reference=new_id).exists()

    return new_id
```

Recursion helps to make the code easier to read, but it almost allways is slower than iteration. You can read more about it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543259/9225671) or in this [quora thread](https://www.quora.com/In-Python-which-is-more-efficient-to-use-recursion-or-iteration) (yes, I know, its quora, but this answer there is good).

---

Instead of using signals you could override the models `save` method.

**models.py**

```
from .utils import unique_order_reference_generator

class ReservedItem(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.order_reference:
            self.order_reference = unique_order_reference_generator()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

Of course, there is the question of why you are doing the random generation at all. Can you not use a sequential id, like djangos pk-by-default `AutoField`?

You could even just get the biggest number so far and increment it (asuming that `order_reference` is a numeric field):

```
max_1 = ReservedItem.objects.all().aggregate(
    Max('order_reference'))['order_reference__max']
max_2 = Order.objects.all().aggregate(
    Max('order_reference'))['order_reference__max']
new_order_reference = max(max_1, max_2) + 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ralf. I will solve it now with the ´save´ method. The reason I didn't use the primary key is that this order id (together with a customer token) will be used to display event tickets. pk's/numbers you could always guess correctly. Adding some letters, it makes it way more difficult. That was my reasoning behind it.